# Array data to be filled into a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dynamic-arrays

`var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];`

The data of the array must be filled in to the table as shown below using JavaScript.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you want to render a table using javascript?
Can you share some code?

Comment: This is not a question. This is a request for code.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly dont make a habit of asking for free code.

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
   let a = arr[i];
   let b = a + 5;
   if(arr.indexOf(b)!= -1) {
       let tdtag1 = document.createElement("td");
       let tdtag2 = document.createElement("td");
       let trtag = document.createElement("tr");
       let trText1 = document.createTextNode(a);
       tdtag1.appendChild(trText1);
       let trText2 = document.createTextNode(b);
       tdtag2.appendChild(trText2);
       trtag.appendChild(tdtag1);
       trtag.appendChild(tdtag2);
       document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(trtag);
   }
   else if(a == 5) {
      let tdtag1 = document.createElement("td");
      let trtag = document.createElement("tr");
      let trText1 = document.createTextNode(a);
      tdtag1.appendChild(trText1);
      trtag.appendChild(tdtag1);
      document.getElementById("myTable").appendChild(trtag);
   }
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
let tbl = document.createElement('div');
tbl.setAttribute('id','tab');
document.body.appendChild(tbl);
document.getElementById('tab').innerHTML = "<table border = '1' style='border-collapse: collapse;'  width='100'>" +'<tr>' + '<td >'+ arr[0] + "</td>" + '<td >'+ arr[5] + "</td>" + '</tr>' + '<tr>' + '<td>' + arr[1] + '</td>' + '<td>' + arr[6] + '</td>' + '</tr>' + '<td>' + arr[2] + '</td>' + '<td>' + arr[7] + '</td>' + '</tr>'+'<tr>' + '<td>'+ arr[3] + "</td>" + '<td>'+ arr[8] + "</td>" + '</tr>'+'<tr>' + '<td>'+ arr[4] + "</td>" + '<td>'+ ' ' + "</td>" + '</tr>';
```

```css
td{
text-align:right;
}
```